# Analytics Recipe - Inner Join not showing any records for dataset

Tags: analytics

I have created a simple recipe that pulls data from a custom object. I added a join node to be able to see a user's Full Name instead of ID. This all worked fine. I can explore the lens and see the data.
[image: Custom object input]

I am now trying to add an Input that is derived from a csv. When the sandbox was created we did not migrate any cases, so I have exported data to csv to include in this recipe. I have added a filter for Create Date >= 1/1/2021.
[image: CSV]
The problem I am running into is when I try and join Cases to the rest of the recipe.  You'll see here the join between the Cases CSV, and the custom object:
[image: No results]
When I first added the join it defaulted to LookUp. It was giving me too much data. I only want to see matching rows between the two, so I have changed the join from LookUp to Inner Join. I do not want to see records from either input unless they have a matching record from the other input.

As soon as I choose Inner Join my preview results come up empty. I ran the recipe and explored the lens anyway (as I have had issues with the Preview in the past), and no results are found. Any thoughts on what is incorrect here? I have taken some of the Account IDs to look at and confirmed both have the custom object record and a case.
[image: Inner Join]